# Excluding README section from godoc for Github project

Tags: go, github, godoc

I have a [Github project](https://github.com/sanggonlee/pogo) with `README.md`. For the purpose of godoc, I added `doc.go` file but didn't mean to include the `README.md` in godoc. Currently the README is showing up as the [first section in godoc](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/sanggonlee/pogo). Is it possible to hide the README section at all?

Comment: No, there is not. [File an issue](https://golang.org/s/pkgsite-feedback) to give feedback on their decision to change how package documentation should be structured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a good solution for this, simply put your `README.md` file in a [`docs` folder on Github](https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/creating-a-repository-on-github/about-readmes) and it will not show up in the godoc, but still display on Github.

I did this for [my project on Github](https://github.com/ddrake12/wgowut) and you can see the [godoc does not show the `README.md`content](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/ddrake12/wgowut).

##### EDIT:

After making the appropriate changes to your github repository, you will need to publish a new patch version to get `pkg.go.dev` to update with the changes.

Comment: I could've sworn it did as you said, but for some reason now the README's showing up on godoc again: https://github.com/sanggonlee/pogo

Comment: @Iblisto you probably just need to force `pkg.go.dev` to update. I think I've done this in the past using `go get` but if you look here apparently you can hit a URL as well: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/38848. Let me know if this works and I will update my answer with this information

Comment: @Iblisto I had some time and tried playing around with this but couldn't get it to update on `pkg.go.dev` using any method. You may need to publish a patch version (v1.0.1) to get it to update. Can you try that?

Comment: Ahh that seems to have worked! Sorry I probably wasn't thinking right. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to hide the README section at all?

No. Unless you omit that file or rename it.